# DataSet created in code not Binding to ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, dataset, binding

I have a WPF User Control with a ListView in it that is created based on the DataSet that is passed to it:

```
public void PopulateList(DataSet ds) {
        listView.View = CreateGridViewColumns(ds.Tables[0]);
        listData.DataContext = ds.Tables[0];
}

private GridView CreateGridViewColumns(DataTable dt) {
        // Create the GridView
        var gv = new GridView {AllowsColumnReorder = true};

        // Create the GridView Columns
        foreach (DataColumn item in dt.Columns) {
            var gvc = new GridViewColumn
                          {
                              DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(item.ColumnName),
                              Header = item.ColumnName,
                              Width = Double.NaN
                          };
            gv.Columns.Add(gvc);
        }

        return gv;
    }
```

Now I create the user control in code and call it's PopulateList with the appropriate dataset and this is where the problems are starting:

If I pass in a dataset that was created from a call to the database the list view shows all the data but if i pass in a DataSet that i created in code the ListView shows the Columns but will not show the data

```
//This is a function that hides the DB call return type is DataSet    
var dsPatientSmokingStatusHistory = DataRepository.PatientSmokingStatusProvider.GetHistory(PatientId);
        //radGridViewPatientSmokingStatus.DataSource = dsPatientSmokingStatusHistory.Tables[0];

        var dt = new DataTable();
        string c1 = "Date".PadLeft(23).PadRight(23);
        string c2 = "Status".PadLeft(20).PadRight(50);
        dt.Columns.Add(c1);
        dt.Columns.Add(c2);
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in dsPatientSmokingStatusHistory.Tables[0].Rows) {
            var dataRow = dt.NewRow();
            dataRow[c1] = ((DateTime)row["Date"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            dataRow[c2] = row["Status"].ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
            dt.Rows[i].AcceptChanges();
            i++;
        }

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dt.TableName = "Table";
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        ds.AcceptChanges();

        smokingStatusGrid.GridWidth = 455;
        smokingStatusGrid.GridHight = 97;
        //This line does not show data
        smokingStatusGrid.PopulateGrid(ds);
        //This line will show data
        smokingStatusGrid.PopulateGrid(dsPatientSmokingStatusHistory);
```

Is there a difference between these two datasets that i don't know about that is preventing me from databinding to it?

Also the user control is being used as an ElementHost in a WinForms application (not sure if this makes a difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code says:

```
DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(item.ColumnName)
```

This [binding constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597578.aspx) takes a string paramter which as per MSDN is *"The initial [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) for the binding"* and is of datatype System.Windows.PropertyPath. I guess, since system tries to find a property with the same name in your class, and your string (item.ColumnName) has spaces at start, it runs into a problem (properties can't start with a space).

Would recommend you to take off the padding that you are doing in column name of your table. Apply any padding/margins in the Header of your GridView.